# Get local path of uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
Path.GetFileName (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName).ToString ();
Convert.ToString (System. IO. Directory. GetParent (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
```

This code did not take File location path. It is taken this path `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0\\kathir.doc`, but cautious document file  is stored in D: drive... Please help how to get the correct path.

My Code

```
public string GetDataFromFile1()
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        if (FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength < 512000)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
            FileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);

            DocToText docToText = new DocToText(filepath);
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            switch (Extension.ToUpper())
            {
                case ".DOC":
                    ResumeContent = docToText.Extract();
                    break;
                case ".DOCX":
                    ResumeContent = docToText.Extract();
                    break;
                case ".PDF":
                    ResumeContent = docToText.ExtractPDFtoWord();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            str = "File uploaded successfully!";
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in this line:

```
string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
```

You need to use the value from the previous row, like this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/") + filename;
FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

Maybe the last line is now unnecessary.

Comment: string path = Server.MapPath("~/") + filename;
FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(path); This code get the working folder location path only. I need Uploaded file path

Comment: Please explain what you mean by uploaded file path. Did you mean the URL? Can you give an example to make yourself clear?

Comment: Uploaded file path means File Location path in local machine

Comment: But the 'uploaded path' is the path you use as parameter in FileUpload.SaveAs.